# SoftKeyboardType in pure as3 app

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I'm not using flex, just pure as3. In flex input text component i have softKeyboardType property for mobile devices but in as3 TextField i can't find replacement.

Answer (score -1):

you can use stagetext in as3

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html